# angular2 - Change color button dynamically

Tags: css, angular, typescript, styles

I am creating an application in angular 2 and typescript.

I want to put some background color in my buttons depending on an variable.

```
<div>
  <button md-button>1. Choose travel</button>
  <button md-button>2. Choose seats</button>
  <button md-button>3. Fill data</button>
  <button md-button>4. Pay</button>
</div>
```

I have a variable in my component:

```
currentStep: number = 1; //1 Select travel, 2 Choose seats, 3 Fill data, 4 Pay
```

And for example, I want that when the currentStep is equal to 3, the third button change his background color to blue.

Which is the best way to achieve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: you want to apply on click or when?

Comment: whenever the variable changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ngClass`:

```
[ngClass]="{'fill-data-btn': currentStep == 3 }"
```

In you css:

```
.fill-data-btn{
background-color: blue;
}
```

Just to give you an idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>
  <button [style.background]=" currentStep === 1 ?'blue':'otherColor'" md-button>1. Choose travel</button>
  <button [style.background]=" currentStep === 2 ?'blue':'otherColor'" md-button>2. Choose seats</button>
  <button [style.background]=" currentStep === 3 ?'blue':'otherColor'" md-button>3. Fill data</button>
  <button [style.background]=" currentStep === 4 ?'blue':'otherColor'" md-button>4. Pay</button>
</div>
```